# Cakephp variables differ on the server

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I've just uploaded my first CakePHP 2.3 app, and I can't get it to work. It seems that everything I read from the database is having different variable structure than it had on my local webserver.

DebugKit check confirmed this, for example it reads `>item>0...` on the online version, and `>item>Item...` on the local version. I'm using CakePHP verison 2.3.7.

This is how $item is fetched in the controller:

```
$item = $this->Item->find('first', array('conditions' => array('slug' => $slug)));
```

and this is how I'm trying to read something in the view:

```
$item['Item']['tekst']
```

It makes no sense to change everything to `$item['Item']['0']`, and even than it wouldn't work on my local webserver. How can I make it work the same way locally and online?

Comment: its may be due to different os, means problem dye to case-sensitive system,may be model not working...just assumption,so please provide details of your os of both server and local

Comment: I guess it was an enviroment clash.. This was an attempt to test the app online before deployment, so I've put it in a subfolder on a hosting that already has a Cakephp 1.3 app in the root. Everything works fine when this app is on its own.

Answer (score 1):

It's very hard for others to diagnose problems like this without access to the app and server. However, as a first step, I'd suggest re-enabling CakePHP's default home page, and seeing if it reports any errors.

Remember when you first install Cake, you get a page that looks like this:

[image]

Well, the first step would be to view that page and resolve any issues it reports.

To re-enable that page, if you've deleted it's files already, you'll need to download a fresh copy of Cake, and add in the files:

/app/View/Layous/default.ctp
/app/View/Pages/home.ctp
and
/app/webroot/css/cake.generic.css